# Codility- PassingCars - zero performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm doing codility tasks. I am currently on the Passing Car quest - https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/passing_cars/ ;

My code got 100% Correctness but 0% Performance.

In all Performance tests I have "TIMEOUT ERROR
running time:> 6.00 sec., time limit: 0.38 sec. "

How to improve it to improve performance?

This is my code:

```
function solution (A){

var len= A.length;
var checker= 0;

for(i=0; i<A.length; i++) {

    if (A[i] === 0){

        var check = i+1

        for (j= check; j<A.length; j++) {

            if (A[j] === 1){
                checker +=1
            }
        }
    }
}

if (checker === 1000000000){
    return -1
}

return checker
}
```

Comment: For starters you're storing `A.length` but not using `len` anywhere, and you are iterating over the array much more than the expected worst-case complexity, O(N). Think of a way you can iterate your array once. That being said, this kind of question _probably_ belongs on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double (nested) loop isn't necessary. It causes you to stall your code over the time limit.

Instead you need to pass through the loop only once by determening the increment rule of number of passes. Here is my solution that got 100%:

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {

    /**
     * The solution is quite simple instead of passing through double loops
     * you only increment your counter when you meet a car going West
     * and you increment by number of cars going East that you've seen so far.
     */
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        int numCarsGoingEast = 0;
        int numPassing = 0;

        if (A.length > 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

                if (A[i] == 0) {

                    numCarsGoingEast++;
                } else {

                    numPassing += numCarsGoingEast;
                }

                if (numPassing > 1000000000) return -1;
            }
        }

        return numPassing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer of complexity O(N) you can't have nested loops.
But you can have successive loops through the array since O(2N) ~ O(N) ! 
(Of course, O(2N) has double the computations of O(N) in actual practice but in Big O notation we only worry about order of magnitude differences, i.e. O(N^2) v O(N).)

This means that you need to stop coding. Instead turn off your PC and use pencil +  paper to find a simple method of solving the problem with only one or two successive scans of the cars array.

This problem boils down to either:

(A) Finding a way to count the 1s in the array that lie right of the index of each 0 in the same array. That gives us the number of passing car-pairs for each eastbound car. When we sum these numbers for all 0s  found in the cars array we get the final result.

or

(B) Counting the number of 0s to the left of each 1 encountered as the array is scanned from left to right. This tells us the number of car-pairs for each westbound car.

To do it via method A you first need to count all the 1s in the array that lie to the right of each 0. Suppose we start scanning the array rightwards from element 0, we can only do this by firstly counting all the 1s in the array - and this will take a separate loop through the array to find the total number of 1s in it. This results in a O(2N) performance, adequate but not optimum.
But if we scan from the end of the array (element N - 1, where N = A.length) and advance leftward by decrementing our loop index, we can update our count of 1s as we go along and in this way we only need to do a single loop through the array and we achieve optimal O(N) performance.

With method B, if we scan the array from left to right we only need one scan of the array as we can update the count of 0s to the left of each 1 that we meet. So this method also takes just one loop through the array and is also optimal O(N) performance.

I leave the rest to you.